# redirect based on cookie information

Tags: javascript

I want to redirect visitors based on cookie information.
For example, here's scenario: Visitor visits the website, he will be presented with modal, which asks for ZIP code, let's say he uses 33146 as zipcode, this is miami zip code, which saves the zip in the cookie, and redirect to /collections/miami/

I have tried to make something like this, although everything works fine before the redirection, saves zipcode to cookie. I'm having a refresh loop, that meaning, first it redirects to /collections/miami and keeps doing that until the address bar is something like: /collections/miami/collections/miami/collections/miami/collections/miami/ which results in endless loop.

```
function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

$(window).on('load',function(){
  if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1){
    $('#openModal').dialog({modal : true});
    var year = 1000*60*60*24*365;
    var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + year);
    document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
  }else{
    var zip_code = getCookie('zip_code');
    let LA = zipcodesLosAngelesUSA.includes(Number(zip_code))
    if(LA){
      var link = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname + 'los-angeles'
      document.location.href = link
    }else{
      invalid.style.display = 'block'
    }

    let ARIZONA = zipcodesArizonaUSA.includes(Number(zip_code))
    if(ARIZONA){
      var link = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname + 'arizona'
      document.location.href = link
    }else{
      invalid.style.display = 'block'
    }

    let TORONTO = zipcodesTorontoCAD.includes(String(zip_code))
    if(TORONTO){
      var link = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname + 'toronto'
      document.location.href = link
    }else{
      invalid.style.display = 'block';
    }

    let MIAMI = zipcodesMiamiUSA.includes(Number(zip_code))
    if(MIAMI){
      var link = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname + '/collections/miami/'
      document.location.href = link
    }else{
      invalid.style.display = 'block';
    }

    let NYC = zipcodesNycUSA.includes(Number(zip_code))
    if(NYC){
      var link = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname + 'nyc'
      document.location.href = link
    }else{
      invalid.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }

submit.addEventListener("click", function(){
  let LA = zipcodesLosAngelesUSA.includes(Number(input.value))
  if(LA){
    var year = 1000*60*60*24*365;
    var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + year);
    document.cookie = "zip_code="+Number(input.value)+";expires=" + expires.toUTCString();

    var link = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname + 'los-angeles'
    document.location.href = link
  }else{
    invalid.style.display = 'block'
  }

  let ARIZONA = zipcodesArizonaUSA.includes(Number(input.value))
  if(ARIZONA){
    var year = 1000*60*60*24*365;
    var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + year);
    document.cookie = "zip_code="+Number(input.value)+";expires=" + expires.toUTCString();

    var link = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname + 'arizona'
    document.location.href = link
  }else{
    invalid.style.display = 'block'
  }

  let TORONTO = zipcodesTorontoCAD.includes(String(input.value))
  if(TORONTO){
    var year = 1000*60*60*24*365;
    var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + year);
    document.cookie = "zip_code="+String(input.value)+";expires=" + expires.toUTCString();

    var link = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname + 'toronto'
    document.location.href = link
  }else{
    invalid.style.display = 'block';
  }

  let MIAMI = zipcodesMiamiUSA.includes(Number(input.value))
  if(MIAMI){
    var year = 1000*60*60*24*365;
    var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + year);
    document.cookie = "zip_code="+Number(input.value)+";expires=" + expires.toUTCString();

    var link = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname + 'miami'
    document.location.href = link
  }else{
    invalid.style.display = 'block';
  }

  let NYC = zipcodesNycUSA.includes(Number(input.value))
  if(NYC){
    var year = 1000*60*60*24*365;
    var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + year);
    document.cookie = "zip_code="+Number(input.value)+";expires=" + expires.toUTCString();

    var link = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname + 'nyc'
    document.location.href = link
  }else{
    invalid.style.display = 'block';
  }
})
```

Can somebody help me fix this silly bug and enlighten me where I did wrong?

Comment: Are you including this code in every page user visits? If you do thats the error. The code in `$(window).on('load',function(){` redirect to page that redirect once more to the page that again redirect and so on.  You should probably refractor this code to use one function not 4(?) that does same but with different city.

Comment: Every time you redirect, you're reloading, which will make the check again and append to the url. Just check that the location you're in does not already include something appended. BTW this would be easier with a framework supporting routes config (e.g. Angular ).